# mysql update another column to primary key value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to set the value of another column to primary key (auto increment)?

Basically what I am trying to achieve is this

```
ID     Stuff
----   ------
1      1
2      324
3      64
4      94
5      ...
```

Now when I am adding the the fifth row with a query like

```
INSERT into TABLE values(NULL, NULL);
```

So when the second value is `NULL` I want it to be equal to ID.

I tried INSERT triggers but it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context?  This is a very strange requirement; beware of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @eggyal if OP thought that Y might solve X, then there might be others that think that too and instead of leaving them in the wild they will find this question here and will in turn find the proper solution to X

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: Agreed.  But a little more context would help to determine what that "proper solution" is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that in one step, but you can first insert and then update...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to expose a stored procedure, and when the Stuff parameter is null, update the insert with the LAST_INSERT_ID(), otherwise pass the non-null value to the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`ID`,`Stuff`) VALUES(NULL, `ID`);
```

Comment: For the record, this doesn't work; the query succeeds, but the `Stuff` field will contain 0.

Comment: Then only triggers that run after insert, something along the lines of  `UPDATE table SET stuff=IFNULL(NEW.stuff, NEW.id)`